# /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 13: exec: image: not found

Tags: docker, containers, devops, scanf, devsecops

I am encountering this issue : `/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 13: exec: image: not found`
when trying to add an image to anchore/engine-cli on docker.

Specifically I run :
 `docker run anchore/engine-cli image add XXXXX:"image-name"`

Could anyone help me on this ? I am running docker desktop on a Windows 10

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

If you check the documentation of the [official anchore/engine-cli image](https://hub.docker.com/r/anchore/engine-cli), to use the container you need to run:

```
docker run -e ANCHORE_CLI_URL=<my engine endpoint>/v1/ -it anchore/engine-cli
```

Then, from the shell you can use the `anchore-cli` command and add a new image with:

```
anchore-cli image add <imgage>
```

Answer (score 1):

That [image on Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/anchore/engine-cli) contains documentation for how to use it:

> To use the container simply run: `docker run -e ANCHORE_CLI_URL=<my engine endpoint>/v1/ -it anchore/engine-cli`
>
> From the shell you can now use 'anchore-cli': anchore-cli system
> status to get system status anchore-cli image list to list images
> `anchore-cli image add <img>` to add a new image for analysis
> `anchore-cli evaluate check <img>` to get the policy evaluation for an
> image.

So you should be able to run commands like:

```
docker run -it --rm anchore/engine-cli anchore-cli image add XXXXX:"image-name"
```

E.g.

```
$ docker run -it --rm anchore/engine-cli anchore-cli image --help
Usage: anchore-cli image [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Options:
  -h, --help  Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  add       Add an image
  content   Get contents of image
  del       Delete an image
  get       Get an image
  import    Import an image from anchore scanner export
  list      List all images
  metadata  Get metadata about an image
  vuln      Get image vulnerabilities
  wait      Wait for an image to analyze
```

However, I'd note that this image was last pushed 2 years ago, and the [GitHub repo for the project](https://github.com/anchore/anchore-cli) makes no mention of docker images pushed to GHCR or Docker Hub. All installation options supported by the project involve installing it locally on your machine.